# Kendo UI grid sync on error

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I use razor Html Helper to create a Kendo UI Grid. The grid is created so the edition of a record is done via a popup window form. Here is the code

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyObject>()
              .Name("grid")
              .Editable(edit => edit
                  .Enabled(true)
                  .Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)
              )
              .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  // Column declaration
              })
              .ToolBar(toolbar =>
              {
                  toolbar.Create());
              })
              .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                  .Ajax()
                  .Model(model => model.Id(m => m.Id))
                  .ServerOperation(false)
                  .Events(e =>
                  {
                      e.Error("error_handler");
                      e.Sync("sync_handler");
                  })
                  .Read("Read", "MyController")
                  .Create(c => c.Action("Create", "MyController"))
                  .Update(u => u.Action("Edit", "MyController"))
              )
        )
```

I set a handler on both error and sync event of my datasource. The sync handler force a read from the server since some data must be refreshed on create and update operation. The error handler is supposed to prevent the refresh of the grid if an error occur on create or update. Here are both of my handlers

```
 function error_handler(e) {
        if (e.errors) {

            $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").one("dataBinding", function (ss) {
                ss.preventDefault(); // cancel grid rebind if error occurs
            });    
        }
    }

    function sync_handler(e) {
        e.sender.read();
    }
```

My problem is that even if i call `ss.preventDefault` on the sync action, my sync handler is call anyway and the call to `e.sender.read()` cause my popup window form to close. If i remove my sync handler, the `ss.preventDefault` call prevent my popup window form to close correctly, so the problem really is about the sync handler which is always call, even on error. Any idea how I can handle this ?

---

I ended up doing this, not the best but at least fix mt problem

```
function error_handler(e) {
    if (e.errors) {

        e.sender.preventSync = true;

        $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").one("dataBinding", function (ss) {
            ss.preventDefault(); // cancel grid rebind if error occurs
            // do some stuff here
        });

    }
}

function sync_handler(e) {

    if (!e.sender.preventSync)
        e.sender.read();

    e.sender.preventSync = false;
}
```

Comment: I am facing exact the same problem, I wonder if you find your solution yet?

Comment: @shole see my update with my solution